# Why sometimes we have to add .values when we do elementwise operation in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a dataframe looks like

```
    A
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

and when I run:

```
a = df.loc[np.arange(0,2)] / df.loc[np.arange(2,4)]
```

I get

```
     A
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
```

I know I could get the right result by writing

```
a = df.loc[np.arange(0,2)].values / df.loc[np.arange(2,4)]
b = df.loc[np.arange(0,2)] / df.loc[np.arange(2,4)].values
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: In a sense all results are right, depending on what you want.  You didn't show the final `a` and `b`.  The indices differ.  `numpy` arrays don't have fixed indices, data frames do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to pandas is `index` and `columns` sensitive, when you do the calculation the hidden key for them get match first , if we only need to get the value match and remove the impact of index and columns is adding `.values` or `to_numpy()` , however, index also bring some advantage as well

Example 1 index not match so the value will return NaN

```
s1=pd.Series([1],index=[1])
s2=pd.Series([1],index=[999])
s1/s2
1     NaN
999   NaN
dtype: float64
s1.values/s2.values
array([1.])
```

Example 2 index match so pandas will return the value when the index match

```
s1=pd.Series([1],index=[1])
s2=pd.Series([1,999],index=[1,999])
s1/s2
1      1.0
999    NaN
dtype: float64
```